# I have an array that I am pushing to a php file, how can I interprate the way php sees it and save it to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

**FOR ANYONE FOLLOWING ALONG SO FAR**; I have gotten to the point where I have learned that my html page is making the request to open the php file but it isn't posting any data to it. If anyone knows what is wrong please let me know.

This is what I have on the front end so far.

```
stackVar.push([place.name, websiteName, place.rating, place.international_phone_number, place.id, place.formatted_address, place.types[0]]);
//code for saving to a file will go here

if(results.length == stackVar.length){

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'http://www.server.com/saveF.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.send(JSON.stringify(stackVar));
}
```

Okay so I have learned some things but I am still not quite there yet... Here is what I have as far as the php goes...

```
<?php   $conn = new mysqli($sn, $un, $pw, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



$bInfo = $_POST["stackVar"];
$infoEncoded = json_encode($bInfo);
$getsome = $infoEncoded[0][0];
$sql = "INSERT INTO companies(company) VALUES ('$getsome')";
echo $getsome;



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close()
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like PHP... which language are you trying to use? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looks more like he doesn't have his SQL statements properly formatted.

Comment: php tag is wrong here. it looks more like javascript

Comment: I need to use php and mysql, the point is that i am new to them and don't know exactly what i am doing. So i wrote it in a way that makes sense not in a way that is correct. The top is javascript which I am trying to send to a php page to then save to mysql.

Comment: It looks like you're sending a json object. You can just `json_decode()` the string on PHP and then iterate over you object to get your POST data.

Comment: @bos570 Is there a link that you could send me to where I could review how that is done? Would I just set a variable to the post like "$dePost = json_decode('$_POST')" and then a for loop iterating through $depost[i][x] and save that to mysql?

Comment: @kchason I am trying to save the array stackVar to mysql. I need stackVar[x][0] to be the name stackVar[x][1] to be the website ect... I added and update. I can get php to save variables to a database but I can't get php to save my $_POST  to a database yet.